# Laravel, how to avoid n + 1 issue in private chat api structure?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

i'm trying to create an api JSON response structure that looks like the following:

```js
[
  {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "jon abraham",
  "email": "jonabe2442@gmail.com",
  "image": "/images/avatar-default.jpg",
  "messages": [
    {message: 'hello!', user_id: 1}, 
    {message: 'yo!', user_id: 3}
   ]
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "sherry hopkins",
  "email": "shop2663@gmail.com",
  "image": "/images/avatar-default.jpg",
  "messages": [
    {message: 'hey!', user_id: 2}, 
    {message: 'hi!', user_id: 3}
   ]
  }
]
```

The JSON response represents a list of all the users that belongs to the same company that the current logged in user belongs to. It will also display an array of messages between that user and the current logged in user (empty array if there are no messages).

I've managed to create most of my desired api structure except the messages part due to having troubles establishing an appropriate database structure/eloquent relationship for private chat.

Here's my private chat database structure.

**Conversation**

| id | participant_1_id | participant_2_id

**Conversation_messages**

| id | sender_id | receiver_id | text

Here's my controller code that returns the api:

```html
public function userWithMessages
    {   

     $user = Auth::user();
        $company_ids = $user->companies()->pluck('companies.id')->toArray();

        $users = User::join('company_user', 'users.id', 'company_user.user_id')
                ->join('companies', 'company_user.user_id', 'companies.id')
                ->whereIn('companies.id', $company_ids)
                ->select('users.name', 'users.email', 'users.image')
                ->get();

     return response()->json($users, 200);

    }
```

I'm trying to write my query so that I don't come across the n + 1 issue, but I can't seem to find a relationship to conversations from users. The reason being, on the conversations table, I don't know if the user_id is `participant_1_id` or `participant_2_id` meaning I can't use a `hasMany` relationship for example.

Is there a way where I can get messages data from the users in respect to the current logged in user without writing a foreach loop and querying each user ( n + 1 ) issue.

Comment: I think your database structure could be improved, to not only simplify the problem, but also to make your chat service more versatile (easily support group chats). Is that an option, or are you specifically looking for a solution to _this_ problem?

Comment: Also in your API response, you're not distingishing between messages belonging to different conversations. Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose the following database structure. This will support not only multiple conversations between users, but also more than two participants per conversation, thus allowing you to have group conversations.

```
user
-   id
-   first_name
-   last_name
...

conversations
-   id
-   created_at
-   updated_at

conversation_user
-   id
-   conversation_id
-   user_id
-   created_at

message
-   id
-   conversation_id
-   user_id
-   message
-   created_at
-   updated_at
```

The model definitions and relationships for the aforementioned schema would look something like this:

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function conversations() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Conversation::class)->latest('updated_at');
    }

    public function messages() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class)->latest();
    }
}

class Conversation extends Eloquent
{
    public function participants() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->oldest();
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class)->latest();
    }
}

class Message extends Eloquent
{
    public function conversation() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Conversation::class);
    }

    public function sender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

To find all users with their conversations, you can use the following query. This will use two queries to find all users and conversations.

```
$users = User::with('conversations')->get();
```

To find all users with their messages, you can use the following query. This will use two queries to find all users and conversations.

```
$users = User::with('messages')->get();
```

To find all users with their conversations and messages, you can merge the above queries. This will use three queries to find all users, conversations and messages. Note however that the messages will not be nested underneath the conversations.

```
$users = User::with('conversations', 'messages')->get();
```

**Edit:** Something like the following will get you all users, together with any conversation(s) they have had with the current user. If you also include `conversations.messages` in your `with()` call, you'll get the messages in those conversations too. Although this could quickly become a large data set.

```
$user = Auth::user();

$users = User::with([
        'conversations' => function ($query) use ($user) {
            return $query->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($user) {
                return $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
            });
        },
        'conversations.messages',
    ])
    ->get();
```

I'm happy to answer any follow-up questions you may have about the above.

Comment: Thanks fubar, I can go with your database structure, but what I need from the query is just the conversation that belongs to that user with the current logged in user (I hope i'm making sense).

Comment: So basically it should return one conversation per user (because each user would have only one conversation at the most with the current logged in user).

Comment: To be clear, when you say conversation, do you mean the `Conversation` model, or all the `Message` models that comprise a `Conversation`?

Comment: The Conversation model, because using `User::with('conversations')` would return me all the conversations that user would have (but I just want the conversation that user has had with the current logged in user).

Comment: I've updated my answer. You could wrap that logic into a query scope, if you plan to re-use it many times.

Comment: I've implemented this today, but it seems that `$query->wherePivot('user_id', $user->id);` does not work. I think the pivot only relates the `user_id` of that user in the query but does not take into consideration other users id's because the pivot table does not match that.

Comment: Can you dump the SQL query and parameter bindings and post them here?

Comment: "select * from `users` inner join `company_user` on `users`.`id` = `company_user`.`user_id` inner join `companies` on `company_user`.`user_id` = `companies`.`id` where `companies`.`id` in (?)"

Comment: It needs to be the conversation query that runs after this one.

Comment: "select * from `conversations` inner join `conversation_user` on `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_user`.`conversation_id` where `conversation_user`.`user_id` in (?) and `conversation_user`.`user_id` = ? order by `created_at` desc

Comment: Cheers. So the query is trying to find `conversations`, but using the same `converasation_user` twice with two different `user_id` values. I've modified the query to use `whereHas` instead. This is untested, as I don't have a Laravel install to hand, but hopefully will work.

Comment: select * from `conversations` inner join `conversation_user` on `conversations`.`id` = `conversation_user`.`conversation_id` where `conversation_user`.`user_id` in (?) and `user_id` = ? order by `created_at` desc

Comment: This is the query I think you need. It's tricky to write it in Eloquent without being able to test it, and I don't have time to do that right now. `SELECT * FROM conversations c INNER JOIN conversation_user cu1 ON (c.id = cu1.conversation_id) INNER JOIN conversation_user cu2 ON (c.id = cu2.conversation_id AND cu2.user_id = ?) WHERE cu1.user_id IN (?) ORDER BY created_at DESC`

Comment: that's fine, you've already been a great help, i'll try putting that inside my conversations closure

Comment: I was tring to get the particpant name to  show them on the chat list , spend days and no result can you help me

Comment: @ReemAziz post a new question, and if you’ve used the same schema as above, reference this question. Outline what you’re trying to do, then I or someone will try to help.

Comment: I already post a qusetion  for the same problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971202/laravel-chat-with-pivot-table-how-to-return-same-users-to-same-chat/48971335#48971335