# Laravel Chat -- prevent creating new room if two users already have one

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot-table, chat

I am developing a chat system. I have three tables `(users , chats , user_chat)` where the user chat is the pivot table.

I want to check every time that same users want to communicate to back to there chat room and don't create a new chat room.

like

[image]

thats means that whenever `**user_id:15**`
and `**user_id:20**` wish to communicate return them to `**chat_room:1**` and not create a new one. How to do it?

I already tried `array_intersect()` but I didn't get any result.

```
public function store(Request $requests){
    //$requests->user()->id;
    $data = $requests->all();
    $username1 = User::select('username')->where('id',auth()->guard('api')->user()->id )->first();
    $username2 = User::select('username')->where('id',$data['recever_id'] )->first();
    $user1Conve[] = Conversation::where('user_id' , '=',auth()->guard('api')->user()->id )->select('chat_room_id')->get();
    $user2Conve[] = Conversation::where('user_id' , '=',$data['recever_id'] )->select('chat_room_id')->get();
    $result = array_intersect($user2Conve, $user1Conve);
    if (count($result) == 0) {

        $chatroom = ChatRoom::create([
            'room_name' => 'محادثة بين' . $username1->username . ' و ' . $username2->username . '', 'sender_id' => auth()->guard('api')->user()->id

        ]);
        $lastId = (int)$chatroom->id;

        Conversation::create(['chat_room_id' => $lastId, 'user_id' => auth()->guard('api')->user()->id]);
        Conversation::create(['chat_room_id' => $lastId, 'user_id' => $data['recever_id']]);

        $message = Messages::create(
            ['message' => $data['message'],
                'user_room_id' => $lastId,
                'user_id' => auth()->guard('api')->user()->id,
            ]);
        $success['chat_room_id'] = $chatroom->id;
        $success['arrayIntersct'] = $result;
        $pusher = new Pusher("418914066f12eac2d5fd", "6e1b5e98b06d7d3ebd7a", "449820", array('cluster' => 'ap2'));
        $pusher->trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', array('message' => $message->message));
    }
    else {

    }

      return response()->json(['code'=>'success','success'=>$success], $this->successStatus);
}
```

Comment: what have you tried?  show your code

Comment: I update my question added my code

Comment: Can you show us the generated SQL?

Comment: Is this a typo question due to the appended square braced on your declarations?  `$user1Conve[]` and `$user2Conve[]`  What data do these contain?  If you are seeking intersection based on a shared column between two arrays of objects then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78125029/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa I think the real answer was using `Conversation::updateOrCreate()` but there's not enough info (esp. the mapping of models to tables.) I voted to close for lacking clarity.

Answer (score 1):

[`->get()` on a query returns a collection.](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#collections)
I assume you added `[]` to "fix" an error complaining about `array_intersect` not having arrays for arguments, but that just creates the structure a level deeper.

You can convert them to plain PHP arrays with [`->toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/collections#method-toarray), but then you will still have an array of `['chat_room_id'=>ID]`, so you you also need [`->pluck('chat_room_id')`](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/collections#method-pluck).

```
$user1Conve = Conversation
    ::where('user_id' , '=', auth()->guard('api')->user()->id)
    ->select('chat_room_id')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('chat_room_id')
    ->toArray()
;
$user2Conve = Conversation
    ::where('user_id' , '=', $data['recever_id'])
    ->select('chat_room_id')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('chat_room_id')
    ->toArray()
;
```

But you don't need to use `array_intersect` and can find the chat room with the query itself.
If you properly define [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) (`users` on `ChatRoom` and `chatrooms` on `User`), then you can simply do:

```
$chatroom = auth()->guard('api')->user()->chatrooms()
    ->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($data) {
        return $query->where('id', $data['recever_id']);
    })
    ->first()
;
if (!$chatroom) {
    // create chatroom
}
```

Comment: If `pluck()` removes relevant/needed information, `pluck()` can be omitted, then just use `array_uintersect()` and in the callback compare the relevant columns.

Answer (score -1):

`array_intersect`  serches for all of the values in array1 whose values exist in array two, So I think you should use it with inversed arrays too:

```
$result1 = array_intersect($user1Conve,$user2Conve);
$result2 = array_intersect($user2Conve, $user1Conve);
if (count($result1) == 0 && count($result2) == 0) {
......
```

Comment: I do truncate  all the data from chats and user_chat and start to create a new chats to test , and your condation not working it return the (else) value

Comment: I don't see why "the inverse" would be needed here. It creates arrays with the same elements.

Comment: And those arrays aren't something `array_intersect` could work with.