# Diff values between arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, difference

I have these two arrays as a result of requests:

```
$f = DocsPf::where('renda', '=', 2)->where('tipo', '=', 'R')->pluck('id');
$f = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

And

```
$d = Documento::where('user_id', '=', $id)->pluck('cad_doc_id');
[4,5,6,7,8]
```

Now I want to make a request to a model only with the difference between those arrays, like:

```php
$missing = Docs::where('id', '=', 9)->first();
```

and

```php
$missing = Docs::where('id', '=', 10)->first();
```

I´ve did

```
$ids = array_diff($f, $d);
        return $ids;
```

...as the brother bellow wrote, but got hits error:

```
array_diff(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, object given
```

Any helps, please?

Comment: Relevant earlier question: [Laravel Chat -- prevent creating new room if two users already have one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48971202/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) on the two arrays to get unique values:

```
$array1 = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$array2 = [4,5,6,7,8];

$uniqueIds = array_diff($array1, $array2); // `[9, 10]`

$missing = Docs::whereIn("id", $uniqueIds)->get();
// Will return a `Collection` of `Doc` models based on the passed `ids`
```

-- Edit --

If `$array1` and `$array2` are `Collection`s, you can use the `diff()` function:

```
$array1 = collect([4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
$array2 = collect([4,5,6,7,8]);

$uniqueIds = $array1->diff($array2);
$missing = Docs::whereIn("id", $uniqueIds)->get();
// Note: You may need to do `$uniqueIds->toArray()` if it complains further.
```

One more alternative, you can convert `$array1` and `$array2` to arrays before using `array_diff()`

```
$uniqueIds = array_diff($array1->toArray(), $array2->toArray());
```

It's a little redundant, but should help demonstrate the difference between an array and a `Collection`

Comment: Thanks, @Vince, but I´ve forgot to say that the array is a result of a request...  so, maybe it is not an array, but an object.

Comment: It's a `Collection`, which is a fancy helper class for arrays in `Laravel`. They can easily be converted to an array, via `->toArray()`, or you can use `->diff()` as demonstrated.